# Milwaukee Sitecore User Group - September 21, 2017

Tags: discussion, status-completed

**Date/Time (EST):** Thursday, September 21, 2017, 5:30 PM

**Date/Time (UTC):** Thursday, September 21, 2017, 22:30

**Location:** [Milwaukee Perficient Office](https://goo.gl/maps/pCUNkpyyB4r), 311 E Chicago Street, Milwaukee, WI

**RSVP:** https://www.meetup.com/preview/Milwaukee-Sitecore-Developers-Meetup/events/242340468

**Organizers:**

- [Derek Dysart](https://twitter.com/ddysart)
- [Paul Plakut](https://www.linkedin.com/in/paulplakut/)
- [Mark Servais](https://twitter.com/mservais)

### Agenda*

- 5:30 - 6:00 PM: Food, refreshments, networking
- 6:00 - 6:10 PM: Intro and announcements from organizers/sponsors
- 6:10 - 7:15 PM: Sitecore and MVC A-to-Z
- 7:15 - 7:20 PM: Short break
- 7:20 - 8:30 PM: Why Sitecore Best Practices Are Important

*times are subject to change for presentations

### Sponsors

- Our location sponsor: [Perficient, Inc.](http://www.perficient.com/)
- Our food and drink sponsor: [Laughlin Constable](https://www.laughlin.com/)

### Presentations

Video links will be provided in the next couple of days after the event.

#### Presentation #1: Sitecore and MVC A-to-Z

**Speaker:** [Corey Smith](https://twitter.com/sitecorey) - [Perficient, Inc.](http://www.perficient.com/) / 2017 Sitecore Technology MVP

Sitecore developers using MVC spend a lot of time working with models, views, and, controllers, but there are a lot of things that execute before, in between, and after those three key letters of Microsoft's web framework. In this session, Sitecore MVP Corey Smith will dive into some of MVC's extension points such as route handlers, model binders, view engines, and more, and show how you can leverage them in your Sitecore projects.

#### Presentation #2: Why Sitecore Best Practices Are Important

**Speaker:** [Mark Servais](https://twitter.com/mservais) - [Perficient, Inc.](http://www.perficient.com/) / 2014 - 2017 Sitecore Technology MVP

This will be an open dialogue around some of the examples I've seen of worst practices, what can be done for remediation, and what you might want to do in the first place before proceeding down a worst practice path..

While a lot of best practices are typically technology related, this dialogue will largely focus on Sitecore best practices with little focus on core on development best practices, meaning this will not be going down the hole of code structures, reviews, etc. and focusing on environment, configuration and content.

Comment: I created the event and started its promotion (i.e. it's now in the sidebar).